# sudo apt-get update - armhf 404 not found

Tags: 14.04

I went through all the existing posts on this but it didn't work. I tried doing

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

which didn't do anything. I also tried running a script i found on other questions and getting rid of the ppa but that didn't work either.... How do i fix this :( ? Or How do i get rid of this error?

I get the following error(Sorry i tried to post an image but it wouldn't let me b/c of my low reputation)

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I would avoid trying to put armhf packages on anything that isn't an armhf operating system... is there a specific reason you're trying ot do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: @Thomas W. I actually do not know why it's trying to install armhf. I think it's because currently i'm trying to install stuff to NVIDIA's jetson tk1 via ubuntu

Comment: @JoKeR I ran the script banish404 but it got stuck and i had to force quit.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/apt/sources.list`, edit the lines which look like

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
```

so they look like this

```
deb [ arch=amd64,i386 ] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb [ arch=amd64,i386 ] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
```

then run `sudo apt-get update` again. The reason for your issue is that the repository you are trying to update from does not support the `armhf` architecture. You can test this yourself by navigating to `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe` in your web browser. You will see `binary-amd64` and `binary-i386` directories, but no `binary-armhf` directory.